# php EMPTY not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a form ONLY if the current row is empty.. Currently the row in my DB is NOT empty. It has a date in it.. 2/10/16 it is set as a VARCHAR though. Anyways, When I use the following.. It still shows me the form even though it shouldnt because the row is NOT empty..

Below is the code

```
order = $_GET['uid'];
$stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_num = :order");
$stmt->execute(array(":order"=>$order));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (empty($row['giventoatpdate'])) {
    echo 
    "
    <form name='atpdate' method='POST'>
    Date Sent to clown?
    <br>
    <input type='text' name='update'>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' name='giventoatpdate'>
    </form>
    ";
}
```

All variable names are correct and spelled correctly.

The select statement is working aswell, Already tested.. I feel it has to do with empty and the data in teh db being a date. 2/10/16

Comment: so, where are we with the question/answer? I tested all this; cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `while` loop:

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    if (empty($row['giventoatpdate'])){
    ...
    }
    else{
    ...
    }

}
```

and make sure that those empty rows, if empty... are indeed empty.

Alternatively and as stated by Luke in comments, different PHP versions could `empty()` differently.

```
if ($row['giventoatpdate'] == ''){...}
```

or another alternative:

```
if ($row['giventoatpdate'] != ''){...} // using a negation instead
```

and inside that `while` loop.

- **IMPORTANT:** Make sure you do not have a default value for the column. If that default value is `0` or `NULL` or other, then that could affect your query and will never be considered as being empty.
- Another to check for, is if your UPDATE didn't introduce any whitespace. If the said column contains a space, then that will also be considered as "not empty". This being the fact upon testing for that also.

---

**Edit:**

After testing, your query may be failing because you are selecting all of your columns with `SELECT *` rather than the `giventoatpdate` column itself.

This being that there are other columns that are not empty.

Therefore, you may need to select the column itself only in the query:

```
SELECT giventoatpdate FROM orders
```

However, make sure you did select the right column.

**N.B.** I just did another test with `SELECT *` and it also worked, so you can scratch my above theory, but not totally leave it out of the equation though.

Comment: `while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{



  if(empty($row['giventoatpdate']))
  {
   echo 
   "
   <form name='atpdate' method='POST'>
   Date Sent to clown?
   <br>
   <input type='text' name='update'>
   <br>
   <input type='submit' name='giventoatpdate'>
   </form>
   ";
  }
 }` Now the row IS empty... made sure of that and it will NOT show my form lol

Comment: To tag onto "Make sure they are indeed empty" make sure that empty is the correct function you should be using, because different versions of PHP treat empty differently. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @Luke3butler Good point Luke, thanks. Edit: Added in an edit.

Comment: Alright, Ill check and update this soon. Gotta run to the store real quick. Sorry ;)

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 no problemo. Keep me posted. I'm always glad to help and provide a solution.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 I know what the problem is now and have made an additional edit to my answer. Reload it and look under **Edit:**. and also about if you have a default value for the `giventoatpdate` column.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 curious. where are we at with this? reloaded the edit?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I actually went in a completely different direction with this, I could not get this to work correctly and had to figure something out quick